# Cypress Test fails with a RangeError

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am currently trying to use cypress to test my application. My test is the following:

```
it.only('goes to the detail page of a person and edits the persons details', () => {
  cy.get('pd-table.hydrated').shadow()
  cy.get('.pd-table-horizontal-scroll .pd-table-row').first().click()

  cy.get('pd-panel-header').should('contain', 'Persönliche Angaben')
  cy.get('pd-button').should('contain', 'Bearbeiten').first().click()
  cy.get('[data-cy="personalAttributes-type"]').click({force: true})
  cy.get('[data-cy="personalAttributes-type"]').within(() => {
     cy.get('pd-dropdown-item.hydrated').eq(3).click({force: true})
  })
  cy.get('[data-cy="personalAttributes-parlID"]').within(() => {
     cy.get('input').type('123456')
  })
  cy.get('[data-cy="personalAttributes-language"]').click({force: true})
  cy.get('[data-cy="personalAttributes-language"]').within(() => {
     cy.get('pd-dropdown-item.hydrated').eq(3).click({force: true})
  })
  cy.get('[data-cy="personalAttributes-salutation"]').within(() => {
     cy.get('input').type('{selectAll} {del} Mister')
  })
})
```

The problem is that cypress allways fails on this line:

`cy.get('[data-cy="personalAttributes-language"]').click({force: true})`

I get the following error:

```
Error:     RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.acceptNode (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:180834:15)
    at collectRoots (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:180853:29)
    at collectRoots (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:180855:12)
    at collectRoots (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:180855:12)
    at collectRoots (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:180855:12)
    at collectRoots (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:180855:12)
    at collectRoots (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:180855:12)
    at collectRoots (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:180855:12)
    at collectRoots (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:180855:12)
    at collectRoots (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:180855:12)
    at collectRoots (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:180855:12)
    at collectRoots (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:180855:12)
    at collectRoots (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:180855:12)
    at collectRoots (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:180855:12)
    at collectRoots (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:180855:12)
    at collectRoots (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:180855:12)
From previous event:
    at resolveElements (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:156590:67)
    at Context.get (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:156601:14)
    at http://localhost:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:168605:17
From previous event:
    at runCommand (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:168584:10)
    at next (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:168727:16)
    at http://localhost:8080/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:168756:18
```

I have no idea why this problem occures. Any help or hints are greatly appreceated.

EDIT:

The relevant extract from the html:

```
<pd-combobox
            v-model-pd="v$.personFutureAttributes?.language?.$model"
            data-cy="personalAttributes-language"
            :items.prop="languageItems"
            :placeholder="$t('global.combobox.placeholder')"
            :selectable="true"
            :error="v$.personFutureAttributes?.language.$error"
            @blur="v$.personFutureAttributes?.language.$touch"
            @pd-combobox="updatePersonAttributes($event, 'language')"
          />
```

Comment: Please share the html of this element `data-cy="personalAttributes-language"`

Comment: I added the html. The error doesnt exist because the tag doesnt get found. I can access the tag earlier in the test without error with the same selector.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Yes the error occured because the browser runs out of memory when you are running a lot of tests. The solution was to disable some tests with .skip or by splitting tests into multiple files or running cypress headless.